# Ternary string to Node class

Tags: java

I have an interview question that still kills my mind, please help.

You have to write a method in Java with a `String` parameter.
That `String` should be a tree of ternary operators (a?b:c). So basically it can be something like:
`a? g?h:j ? u?v:w : p : r?s:t`

```
                            a
                          /   \
                     g?h:j     r?s:t 
                    /     \
               u?v:w       p
```

Something like that, I hope I even wrote it right, because I am really confused.

Then we have a class `Node` that has 2 fields: `left` and `right`:

```
class Node {
     char variableName;         
     Node left, right;
}
```

So you have to return a `Node` with all the Nodes(left, right) from that String.

I hope this is understandable. If you need more information I will provide, but the basic idea here is to get all the nodes right. I was trying to do this using recursion and I still believe that this is right. But I cannot figure out how to do it right.

Comment: Generally, "how do I do this" type questions aren't really on topic here. Instead, try posting the code (in the form of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and asking a specific question like "I tried XYZ, expected ABC, but got 123 instead, what's going on?" Also, I don't think your tree is correct: I would expect only a single letter at each node, with the branches then showing what happens when that letter is true or false.

Comment: I agree with @KevinWorkman. If a tree `Node` equals `g?h:j` does `left` equal `h` or `u?v:w`? But that also prompts the question how can a `Node` equal `g?h:j` when its only fields are of type `char` and `Node`?

Comment: No I know that the tree should have 1 char at the node I just wanted the idea to be clear.

Comment: Kevin Workman.
I know, I should, but I just had no Idea how to even start, and now I see that I was thinking totally wrong.
Anyway thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question can be solved with a very simple [*recursive descent parser*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). The intention behind asking this question is to see if you can implement a recursive algorithm where recursion makes sense, as opposed to asking you to code up a boring recursive factorial to see if you have heard of recursion before.

Here is one possible implementation:

```
static class Parser {
    private int pos = 0;
    private String s;
    public Parser(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
    private void skipSpace() {
        while (pos != s.length() && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(pos))) {
            pos++;
        }
    }
    public Node parse() {
        skipSpace();
        Node res = new Node();
        res.variableName = s.charAt(pos++);
        skipSpace();
        if (pos == s.length()) return res;
        if (s.charAt(pos) == '?') {
            pos++;
            res.left = parse();
            skipSpace();
            if (pos == s.length() || s.charAt(pos) != ':') {
                System.err.println("Syntax error");
                return null;
            }
            pos++;
            res.right = parse();
        }
        return res;
    }
}

public static Node parse(String s) {
    Parser p = new Parser(s);
    return p.parse();
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/AI98xb)

The idea is to use `parse()` method as if it's already written: first we parse the variable name, then we check if it is followed by a question mark. If it is, we consume the question mark, parse from the current position what becomes our left node, skip the colon (or error out if the colon is missing), and finally parse the right node. Skip whitespace as you go.